# Qt 5.1.1 debug error code -1073741521

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I am working in Qt Creator 2.8.1, based on Qt 5.1.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit), Windows 7 64 bit.

I wanted to debug my code, It compiled successfully, But runed with an error (return value -1073741521):

> Starte D:_work_\applications\my_app\debug\my_app.exe...Das Programm ist abgestürzt.
>   D:_work_\applications\my_app\debug\my_app.exe beendet, Rückgabewert -1073741521

I think it is not a problem of the application, because I've tried to create an empty project and debug it, did not work as well.

I have installed the same Qt version on the other PC with Windows 7 running on it, and there everything worked without a problem.

Any ideas what could cause this problem and how can If fix it?

ps. If any important info is missing, Please let me know and I'll try to give it.

Comment: -1073741521 = 0xc000012f. In Windows that can mean STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_NOT_MZ (i.e. missing the .exe signature) or ERROR_DELETE_PENDING (cannot be opened because it is in the process of being deleted). Can you look at in a hex editor, does it definitely look like an .exe? If it's not just this one then your toolchain might be broken somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26604-Runtime-problem-in-Release-mode/page2) for the problem. It states:

> 1) Make sure you have the path system with this
>
> c:\qt\2009.05\qt\bin;c:\Qt\2009.05\bin
>
> respect the order this is important
>
> 2) check your "windows\system32" dir and see if there is any 
>   qt dll's like qtcore4.dll, qtcore4d.dll qtgui.dll qtopengl.dll., etc
>
> if there are, and if you know that you dont have any program that will need them,
>   just deleted them, if not update them with the dll's from c:\qt\2009.05\qt\bin.
>   This should work.
>
> The problem is that if you have the correct path, it will still crash because it will
>   look first in the windows system for the librarys.
>
> And if you update the windows system with qtcore4.dll it will still crash because will
>   use the wrong qtgui.dll and others altought (and this is the nasty part to debug) the error message will still be related with qtcore4.dll.
>
> So in windows\system32 you have to update all of them, or delete all of them.

Although I'd suggest to backup any files before you delete them if this is applicable for you

Comment: So the problem is corrupt QT binaries installed into Windows\System32? Do you know what puts them there?

Comment: This is just what I found in the forum. I did not experience this problem myself but apparently [this helped at least two people](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26213-exited-with-code-1073741511)

Comment: Thank you! It was really the problem of an old version of libraries ( in my case QtCored.dll) in windows\system32.